# FHIR XML Patch Operation - Minimal Working Example

Tags: hl7-fhir

could someone provide me with a MWE for a FHIR PATCH operation in XML format on the public test.fhir.org test server. This is what I got:

**Request:**

```
PATCH http://test.fhir.org/r4/Patient/12345
Content-Type: application/xml-patch+xml 
<replace sel="/name/family/@value">Schmidt</replace>
```

**Error:**

*Error parsing resource Xml (This does not appear to be a FHIR element or resource (wrong namespace "") @ /)*

I similiar JSON operation woks fine:

```
PATCH http://test.fhir.org/r4/Patient/12345
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json
    [{
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/name/0/family",
        "value": "Meyer"
    }]
```

I've searched a lot and couldn't find an MWE for an XML Patch operation, only JSON.

Best
Tobias

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the XML namespace. If you add this line to create a valid XML document, it should work:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: Added the line but still same error:
  
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<replace sel="/name/family/@value">Schmidt</replace>`

Could you test it with a public server of your choice?

Comment: I've tried on http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4, and it does not give me the namespace error you mention. The patch does not work, but that's a different problem and I do not know enough about XML patch to solve it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use FHIRPath patch or JSON patch?